# Is 768Mb RAM @ 333Mhz faster or slower than 512Mb RAM @ 400Mhz?

Tags: memory

I have a simple question, but am not a hardware specialist. I have a small low-budget server with 512 Mb SD RAM, 400 Mhz. I have an extra 256 lying around, but it's 333 Mhz. I know I can add it to the system, and that it would automatically adjust the 400Mhz to 333Mhz. But my question is, which is faster/better for performance: 512 at 400Mhz, or 768 at 333Mhz?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

400Mhz is faster then 333Mhz, as per definition ;)

On the other hand the difference between 333Mhz ram and 400Mhz ram is in most cases negligible from my experience. More ram is  better in most cases, however it depends on the usage pattern. If your server is never using more then 512MB ram, then staying with the 512@400 will be better.

Comment: But since it's probably running windows and goodness knows what else you'll want more memory as 77MHz speed difference is negligle when the computer starts swapping memory to disk.  At that point, you need the extra ram.

Answer (score 5):

You're making a comparison in a vacuum. The performance each will perform is dependant on far too many factors. There are cases where each will outperform the other, so without knowing anything about your usage it's impossible to give a "correct" answer. With RAM being so cheap these days why not lash out and buy some more 400MHz RAM and be done with it?

Answer (score 4):

512 at 400Mhz is faster. But 768 at 333Mhz is bigger :) What is finally faster - depends how ofter your server uses swap.